# Weird Product Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Evaluate the series:

$$\sqrt{1+z} \cdot \sqrt{1+z\sqrt{1+z}} \cdot \sqrt{1+z\sqrt{1+z\sqrt{1+z}}}\cdots\text{upto N terms}$$

How to find the general formula for $N$ terms?

Comment: Is $z$ a complex number?

Comment: @AlexSilva No a variable

Comment: @David Variables are numbers. The question remains: what possible numbers could $z$ be? Is it restricted to non-negative real numbers, for instance?

Comment: Z belongs to Real Number Set

Comment: For the product to converge you need $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+za_n}$ to have limit $1$. So $1=\sqrt{1+z}$, which means $z=0$ is the only option.

Comment: I need a general algebraic expression for n terms. Is such a formula possible?

Comment: $$ a_{0} =\sqrt{1+z}$$
$$ a_{n+1} =\sqrt{1+za_n}$$

 $$ P=\prod_{n=0}^\infty a_n $$

Comment: @Pagode This is just a recursive form. I need a formula for n terms

Comment: So you can further explores a general expression for $a_n$ but it seems non-trivial so make distinction between $z$ cases

Comment: You need recursive form to find the general formula ! Here is the work !

Comment: @Pagode All i need is an expression in simplified algebraic form

Comment: I know but here we give you hint and searsch with you ! Look at dynamic system sequences

Comment: @Pagode I am having no idea for the answer to my own problem

Comment: Try to explores on Internet sequences related to dynamic system

Comment: Begin by case like $ z=-1 , -1<z<0 , z>0$

Comment: @Pagode Thank you for the idea. Trying to understand

Comment: You're welcome , I will search on my side

Comment: @ArnaudMortier If $z=-1$ the product converges

Comment: @Henry right. If $z$ has $0$ in its orbit then it converges, otherwise not.

Comment: What do you call orbit for $z$ ?